# Getting an empty object when I use multipart/form-data post request on Postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multipartform-data, multer

I am testing multer package for the first time, but when I do the post request on Postman it returns an empty object. Reading similar questions from someone who had the same problem I found several answers saying it was a Postman problem. I have tried restarting the server and reopening the program several times but without success.

This is my server settings:

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import authRouter from './routes/auth.js';
import categoryRouter from './routes/category.js';
import productRouter from './routes/product.js';


//DOTENV CONFIG
dotenv.config();
const MONGODB_CONNECTION = process.env.MONGO_URI;

//INITIALIZE APP
const app = express()

//MIDDLEWARES
/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });*/
  
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']
}));



//ROUTES
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/categories', categoryRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter)


//PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5020


//CONNECT MONGODB
const connectDB = () => {
    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_CONNECTION, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    } )
        .then(() => console.log('MONGODB is connected'))
        .catch(err => console.log('MONGODB connection error:', err ))
}

connectDB();

//INITIALIZE SERVER
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log (`Connection is established and running on port ${PORT}`)
)
```

My multer middleware:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads'))
    },
    filename : function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + '__' + file.originalname)

    }
})

const fileFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    if(file.mimetype === "images/png" || file.mimetype === "images/jpg" || file.mimetype === "images/jpeg") {
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
     cb(null, false)
    }


}

export const upload = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter})
```

My test controller:

```
//CREATE PRODUCT
export const createProduct = async (req, res) => {

    res.status(200).json({file: req.file})
    
}
```

My route:

```
import express from 'express';
import { authMiddleware, authAdminMiddleware } from '../middlewares/auth.js';
import { getProducts, createProduct } from '../controllers/product.js';
import { upload } from '../middlewares/upload.js';

router.route('/create-product').post(authMiddleware, authAdminMiddleware, upload.single('image'), createProduct);
```

On Postman :

[image: Headers Request]
[image: Body Request]

Has anyone managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you also please link an image with the body you are sending ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I uploaded the same image twice, I just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that's not entirely correct.

```
res.status(200).json({file: req.file})
```

I'm not sure you can send a file using `response.json`, instead something like:

```
res.sendFile()
```

You also don't have to specifically use `response.status(200)`.

Other than that, I'm not sure you can get the file from the request using `file`, I think it should be `files`, plural.  Unless some middleware you're using is changing that.  To access files use `request.files`.

Also you're declaring the route like this:

```
app.use('/api/products', productRouter)

...

export const createProduct = async (req, res)
```

However doing that I'm not sure how express would know that it's a post request (even if it applies it to all routes), but it's also just not the way it should be used.  Instead do:

```
app.post('/api/products/create_product', createProduct)

...

export const createProduct = async (req, res) => {}
```

Or alternatively:

```
export const productRouter = express.Router()

app.use('/api/products', productRouter)

...

import {productRouter} from './server'

router.post('/create_product', async (req, res) => {})
```

Somewhere I think you have to tell it that you're actually looking for a post request.  You can either directly map routes to the app or you can create a router and "use" the router, but I don't think you should be "using" route handlers directly if they're not pure middleware, like if they're "METHOD" dependent (like POST in this case).

If you've fixed those things then I think it might work, otherwise try try again.